# Drupal Multisite using subfolder

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

i want to have another drupal-site in a subdirectory using multisites. Assuming I have the domain foo.example.com and the folder sites/foo.example.com. I want to new site to be at foo.example.com/bar. So according to the describtion in the settings php i'd simply have to setup a folder sites/foo.example.com.bar.

Well… I did. Yet it does still load the site of sites/foo.example.com/.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to create a symbolic link inside the Drupal root pointing to itself. So in this example, assuming that your Drupal site is in `/var/www/html`, you would do the following at the command line:

```
cd /var/www/html
ln -s . bar
```

Answer (score 0):

I've installed Drupal 7 in a subdirectory using *[multisites configuration](https://www.drupal.org/node/53705)*.

On my [*case*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35485123/4058484) beside the symbolic link I still need to correct the value on *Public file system* using admin account once the instalation is completed. Otherwise [File System Setting](https://www.drupal.org/node/15368) is not work.