# Creating Drupal Multisite with Subdirectory from different Domain

Tags: drupal, nginx, drupal-7, drupal-multi-domain

I'm attempting to create Drupal Multisite. Currently lets say we have below Live Sites in the form

**abc.example.com**
**def.example.com**
**xyz.example.com**

All the Sites are present on the Same server (Nginx Server) in the directories

**/var/www/vhosts/abc.example.com/httpdocs**
**/var/www/vhosts/def.example.com/httpdocs**
**/var/www/vhosts/xyz.example.com/httpdocs**

Now we have to create Blogs for each Live Site, we are looking into Drupal Mutlisite Architecture for the same, so all Sites should point to same codebase, which would ease our maintenance tasks.

We have currently created symlinks for to main/default domain Site directory which is installed at blogs.example.com so symlink is created as

ln -s /var/www/vhosts/blogs.example.com/httpdocs/ /var/www/vhosts/xyz.example.com/httpdocs/blog

And created a folder under **sites** as **sites/xyz.example.com.blog**

But when we open the URL in browser we get "No input file Specified"

We are not sure if the above error is due to some issue in .htaccess, also we are consfused where to add htacess configuration related to MutliSite.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As explained [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5125202/4058484) your symbolic link shall be under `/var/www/vhosts/blogs.example.com/httpdocs` as the installed directory as well as the created **sites** folder. Try also to remove the end slash on `httpdocs/` on your symbolic link:

```
ln -s /var/www/vhosts/blogs.example.com/httpdocs/ /var/www/vhosts/xyz.example.com/httpdocs/blog
```

to `httpdocs` only, like so:

```
ln -s /var/www/vhosts/blogs.example.com/httpdocs blog
```

or do it in 2 lines command:

```
cd /var/www/vhosts/blogs.example.com/httpdocs
ln -s . blog
```

Make sure also that *CNAME* of both `xyz.example.com` and `blogs.example.com` are the same and that the `xyz.example.com` is set as *ServerAlias* to `blogs.example.com` on your vhost. So you should get your site when point your browser to `http://xyz.example.com/blog`.

Once you have login to your new site as the admin, check or put the correct path for *Public file system path* under the following admin menu to **sites/xyz.example.com.blog/files**:

```
Home » Administration » Configuration » Media » File System
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking time to answer the question, +1 for that. But I no longer have access to the environment on which I ws having this issue, but will surely try this on my local environment.